# 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Task[]>

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have below code throwing error

```
taskToday: Observable<Task[]>;
    this.taskToday = Observable.fromPromise(this.dbCollectionService.taskCollection.ref.where('dueDate', '==', moment().startOf("day").toDate()).get().then(doc=>{
                doc.docChanges() .map(
                    d =>  { 
                      const task =  d.doc.data() as Task;
                      const id =  d.doc.id 
                      return { id, ...task};
                    }
                );
            }))
```

Try alot but could not get it.

I am new in angular and firestore, Please help

Comment: You are missing a `return` on a quick glance.

Comment: where I got this code mixed with help from net

Comment: `return doc.docChanges() ......`

Comment: Thanks, slap me.. such a silly mistake

Comment: could you please help me, when I follow this approach, it is affecting when there is any change in collection

Answer (score 0):

You should return the changes,

```
return doc.docChanges() .map(
                    d =>  { 
                      const task =  d.doc.data() as Task;
                      const id =  d.doc.id 
                      return { id, ...task};
                    }
                );
```

Comment: ye I got it with felp from @AJT_82 help

Comment: could you please help me, when I follow this approach, it is affecting when there is any change in collection

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: If any remove any doc in collection it should affected,but its not

Comment: like when we do .snapshotChanges() or valuechange

Answer (score 0):

you should return inside function this type.

```
next: getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]>{return this._http.get<Movie[]>(url_with_params); }
```

And if your code will looks like

```
this: getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]>{this._http.get<Movie[]>(url_with_params); }
```

you'll get error about type void is not assignable